# How to create custom annotation similar to @autowire and @value

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired

We use configuration values from an external source in a large spring application. Is there a way to create a custom annotation so we can 'wire' these configurationvalue providers?

We have a service which provides configuration values based on a number of variables like current environment (dev/prod) and current channel (web/mobile).
Currently this uses static code and does not use spring.
I searched for a way to register a custom annotation with spring and a factory for that annotation like so:

```
@MyConfigurationAnnotation(key="my.config.key", fallbackValue= "1")
private MyConfigValueProvider provider;

...
void someMethod(){
    int val = provider.get(currentEnvironment, Integer.class);
}
```

I'm searching for a way to register some "myConfigAnnotationBeanFactory" to spring which spring calls with the values from the annotation. The factory  then creates a supplier bean for this specific configuration key.

Is something like this possible in spring? With @Autowire and @Value there are already two annotations which do something similar, I just want to register a third kind of wire-mechanism with spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workable solution:
First I created an annotation for my config values

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD })
@Autowired
public @interface ConfigurationValue {
  String name();

  String defaultValue();
}
```

Then I added a BeanPostProcessor/FactoryBean for my configuration values

```
public class ConfigValueBeanProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, FactoryBean<ConfigSupplier> {

  @Autowired
  private EnvironmentConfiguration environmentConfiguration;

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyConfigurableMarkerAnnotationOnClassLevel.class)) {
      List<Field> annotatedFields = FieldUtils.getFieldsListWithAnnotation(bean.getClass(), ConfigurationValue.class);
      for (Field field : annotatedFields) {
        try {
          processAnnotatedField(field, bean);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // do stuff
        }
      }
    }
    return bean;
  }

  private void processAnnotatedField(Field field, Object bean) throws IllegalAccessException {
    boolean accessible = field.isAccessible();
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object o = field.get(bean);
    if (o instanceof ConfigSupplier) {
      ConfigurationValue annotation = field.getAnnotation(ConfigurationValue.class);
      ConfigSupplier configSupplier = (ConfigSupplier) o;
      ConfigSupplier patchedSupplier = configSupplier.withSettingsKeyAndDefault(
          annotation.name(), annotation.defaultValue());
      field.set(bean, patchedSupplier);
    }
    field.setAccessible(accessible);
  }

  @Override
  public ConfigSupplier getObject() throws Exception {
    return new ConfigSupplier(environmentConfiguration);
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return ConfigSupplier.class;
  }
}
```

What happens is this:
Spring autowires my ConfigSupplier with all dependecies. The postprocessor patches this supplier later on in the livecycle with the default value and with the correct configuration key.

It feels a bit hacky and I'm still looking for better alternatives but it works. The best way would propably be to override `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#postProcessProperties` and add logic to create the bean and add the annotation data in one step instead of my two step approach.

Answer (score 1):

Would a combination of `@ConfigurationProperties` and a factory class supplied to a `@PropertySource` help achieve what you want?

e.g.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="some-value", name="my.config.key", factory=MyConfigFactory.class)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="example")
public class ExternalConfig {

    private String name = "default";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }        
}
```

With a factory class that goes and fetches your external properties

```
public class MyConfigFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        // The name will be what you set on the @PropertySource 'my.config.key'
        // The resource is from the value you set on the @PropertySource
        // you could get at that using resource.getResource().getFilename()
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        // set whatever properties needed in the map
        properties.put("example.name", name);
        return new MapPropertySource("my-external-properties", properties );
    }

}
```

Here I've just set `example.name="my.congig.key"`. This will replace the initial value of "default" for the name field in the ExternalConfig.

Comment: Thanks for you answer :)

This seems to be a good starting point. The problem is, that I can't wire primitive datatypes directly since I have to evaluate the environment at runtime.
I'll experiment with this and post if I get it to work for my case